# How open a new tab using servlet response?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports, jsp-tags

I want to open a new tab when I run `index.jsp` file in a web application . And I have used `Show.java` (a servlet) to perform that . The current situation is when I click the `Print` button in `index.jsp` , the content page which I want to open in a new tab is displaying on the current tab . I want to do it using servlet response and not using `javascript` or `jquery` .

This is the I've written in `index.jsp` file ,

```
<form action="Show">            
    <input type="submit" value="Print"/>
</form>

<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter" %>

<%
   JRPdfExporter export = (JRPdfExporter)request.getAttribute("exportIndentObject");
   if (export != null){
         JRPdfExporter export1 = (JRPdfExporter) session.getAttribute("exportIndentObject");
         export1.exportReport();
    }%>
```

This is `Show.java` which I use to keep content,

```
String param ="Terance";     
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("param", param);                
  JRPdfExporter jRPdfExporter = new  JRPdfExporter();                                                                       jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT,                                      this.print();");

  String jsaperFile="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Terance\\Jasper\\JasperReport\\src\\java\\jasper\\Report.jrxml";
System.out.println(jsaperFile);
try
                    {
                        String report=JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jsaperFile);

                        File file=new File(report);
                        if(!file.exists()){
                            throw new JRException("Cannot find the given file .");
                        }

                        JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map);
                        byte[] exportReportToPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

                        ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();
                        response.setContentType("application/pdf;");

                        jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                        jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, sout);
                        jRPdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");

                        request.setAttribute("exportIndentObject", jRPdfExporter);

                        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");        


                        sout.write(exportReportToPdf);      
                        sout.flush();
                        sout.close();              

                    } catch (JRException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

When I use `response.redirect();` , I couldn't get even the `index.jsp` file in browser .

Comment: Your response will go where the request comes from

Comment: @Darshan Lila:- Haven't any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet works on server side, and generate http response to your browser, but it cannot response with any command to open new tab. This depends on user browser settings (to open new window or new tab), so Servlet cannot do this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation  and theories about servlets .

Answer (score 5):

Only for all or none:

```
<form ... target="_blank">
```

So maybe place the print button outside the original form and have its own form tags.

Comment: Thank you for the help . I'll use this .